# Flutter video_360 - AndroidView Height getting cropped?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

https://pub.dev/packages/video_360
https://github.com/kilroy80/flutter_video_360

I am using this package to play 360 videos in a Flutter app, and it uses Exoplayer for Android with `AndroidView` for the widget.

The problem is, the way this package is built is that if I set a `SizedBox` to the `Video360View`, it chops off a portion of the height when I set the MediaQuery screen height.

Instead of resizing the video, the video view is instead resized and no matter what I try I cannot get the full height of the video.

Is there any modification I can make to the package or do some Flutter workarounds to see the whole widget? (I tried the controller's height property, that didn't work either)

UPDATE: I set the Clip to none in AndroidView, and now I know it's the actual implementation that is not taking the full height of the video...

**This only happens in landscape.**